# To install XMLSECURITY library

Tags: linux, centos, yum, vmware, libraries

Trying to build wmvare tools for 32 bit Centos 7. `./configure` complains regarding XMLSECURITY library:

```
Cannot find XMLSECURITY library. Please configure without XMLSECURITY (using --without-xml-security-c), or install the XMLSECURITY libraries and devel package(s).
```

`yum install xml-security-c` not helped:

```
No package xml-security-c available
```

How to install `xml-security`?

I have option `using --without-xml-security-c`. What I will miss in that case?

I have  took branch  stable 10..0.x of vmtools since I expect it will not need newest libs and it will be easier to build.

**UPD**

I have installed `xml-security` :

```
yum install xmlsec1-devel
```

But still have same error. Why `./configure` not sees this lib?

Comment: `yum search xmlsec` ... ... `# yum install xmlsec1-devel`(.i686) .... ... http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7.4.1708/os/i386/Packages/

Answer (score 0):

XMLSECURITY lib´s

```
# yum search xmlsec
.    
  xmlsec1
  xmlsec1-devel
  xmlsec1-gcrypt
  xmlsec1-gcrypt-devel
  xmlsec1-gnutls
  xmlsec1-gnutls-devel
  xmlsec1-nss
  xmlsec1-nss-devel
  xmlsec1-openssl
  xmlsec1-openssl-devel
```

On-line list http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7.4.1708/os/i386/Packages/

Install example : `# yum install xmlsec1-devel`

Comment: This helped to install libs, but I still have the same error. Maybe ./configure is looking for any other directory ?

Comment: Probably install xmlsec1-(gnutls)-devel , or whatever of `{gcrypt, gnutls, nss, openssl}` you want to use.

Comment: I checked `open-vm-tools.spec` from `open-vm-tools-10.1.5-3.el7.src.rpm`. You need to have `xmlsec1-openssl-devel` installed package.

Comment: Have installed xmlsec1-openssl-devel, but still have same error. I have  took branch  stable 10..0.x of vmtools since I expect it will not need newest libs and it will be easier to build. Is that might be related to errors?

Comment: Where I can find open-vm-tools.spec ?

Comment: `open-vm-tools-10.1.10-3.fc27.src.rpm` http://ftp.sun.ac.za/ftp/pub/mirrors/fedora/releases/27/Everything/source/tree/Packages/o/open-vm-tools-10.1.10-3.fc27.src.rpm ... Unpack with `unPack_rpm.sh` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing ... to get the spec file, `open-vm-tools.spec`